# anybody deployed terracotta 5 with security

Tags: security, terracotta, ehcache-3

did anyone implemented terracotta 5(5.3.2) cluster with some security.
I don't find any documentation regarding this topic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in security support in Terracotta 5.x / Ehcache 3.x.

Historically the security features are proposed as enterprise features. They are planned for the future but not yet available.

FYI I work on Ehcache and Terracotta.